# How do you combine Angular 5 with different javascript code sources?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am a bit new to angular.

I want to combine external angular script file and on-page javascript code with angular 5.
I know angular doesnt let you include javascript code in the html components, but I know there is a way.

I create my script file in this way:

```
var scriptElem = angular.element(document.createElement('script'))
scriptElem.attr("src", scriptUrl) // set var appropriately
element.append(scriptElem)
```

But then I need to incorporate javascript code such as this.

```
function A(){

}

function B(){

}

function C(){

}
```

I can render the script element. But I cant put that code in the component because it wont render. So I came up with a solution of putting that code in another script file and loading it dynamically like I did before.
I am not sure if it is the ideal solution.

My goal is to integrate existing javascript code with angular, while not having control of the code inside the external link.

Whats the ideal solution?

Comment: You could add it to the `index.html` file

Comment: It is a bit project. I dont want to put a lot of stuff in it. Especially, things that are not relevant to that spefic part of the project.

Comment: It isn't clear why you want to do this, because Angular is a JavaScript framework and those functions belong somewhere.  What do your functions do? Chances are they belong in a "provider" instance. The index.html file is where your non-angular JavaScript truly belongs because you've already hacked through the framework with your `element.append` call above, that doesn't look good to me.

Comment: The script is loaded requires the functions to exist on the page. It doesnt matter what they do.. If they dont exist when the script loads an error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

As you do want to integrate your existing code. The direct way is to create a script tag and put your js file link into it.

One way is just use **Renderer2** and **ElementRef**. The official document advice uses ElementRef with caution.

I recommend you go and have a look this two classes. The do the same as using  `document.getElementById('')`. Create a script tag and put your js location in it.

---

I just wrote a simple code. Tested on my local.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-js',
  template: `<button class="btn" #iambtn id="iambtn">
            I AM A BUTTON JUST NOW
           </button>`,
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-js.component.css']
})
export class DynamicJSComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('iambtn') imbtn: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // setTimeout(() => {
    this.loadJS();
    // }, 2000);
  }

  loadJS() {
    let scriptTag = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.innerText =
      "console.log('i dont like'); prompt('nest scrpit demo');   document.getElementById('iambtn')";
    console.log(scriptTag, this.imbtn);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.imbtn.nativeElement, scriptTag);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is an interesting approach. I have two questions. Why do you need to create a @ViewChild element. Second, instead of putting an innerText why not to refer a file?

Comment: ViewChild is my favor, you can create an empty tag in your HTML and refer it with ViewChild.  As you said The script is loaded requires the functions to exist on the page and in my code, the loadJS can be trigger when you want.   You can refer a file, almost similar. Here I put script code just for a simple demo.  :)